# Logstash Filter not working when something has a period in the name

Tags: logstash, kibana, filebeat

So I need to write a filter that changes all the periods in field names to underscores. I am using `mutate`, and I can do some things and not other things. For reference here is my current output in Kibana.

[image: Kibana Data]

See those fields that say "packet.event-id" and so forth? I need to rename all of those. Here is my filter that I wrote and I do not know why it doesn't work

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => { "pooooo" => "AW CMON" }
        rename => { "offset" = "my_offset" }
        rename => { "packet.event-id" => "my_packet_event_id" }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I CAN add a field, and the renaming of "offset" WORKS. But when I try and do the packet one nothing changes. I feel like this should be simple and I am very confused as to why only the one with a period in it doesn't work.

I have refreshed the index in Kibana, and still nothing changes. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When they show up in dotted notation in Kibana, it's because there is structure to the document you originally loaded in json format.

To access the document structure using logstash, you need to use `[packet][event-id]` in your rename filter instead of `packet.event-id`.

For example:

```
filter {
    mutate { 
        rename => { 
            "[packet][event-id]" => "my_packet_event_id" 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the JSON parsing directly in Filebeat by adding a few lines of config to your `filebeat.yml`.

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- paths:
    - /var/log/snort/snort.alert
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
  json.message_key: log
```

You shouldn't need to rename the fields. If you do need to access a field in Logstash you can reference the field as `[packet][length]` for example. See [Logstash field references](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#logstash-config-field-references) for documentation on the syntax.

And by the way, there is a [de_dot](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-de_dot.html) for replacing dots in field names, but that shouldn't be applied in this case.